# Best way to show fragments in tabs?

Tags: android, tabs, android-listfragment

I'm writing an app in which each tab must display a different ListFragment view. I've finished working on the ListFragment and it works without any issues. Now, I would like to display them using tabs so that any ListFragment can be accessed by selecting it's respective tab.
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way is to use ActionBarSherlock + ViewPager :

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/

Comment: I have implement using the same and its works well. If you are content with the default tabs available in android you dont need to use tht library but in case you want to customize the tab headings this is a good library

Comment: Would that be compatible with API 8?

Comment: ABS use android support v4 library it is compatible API 8