# can't set action in action bar tab layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new in Android. I create an action bar tab from [here](https://bitbucket.org/Leandros99/android-4.0-actionbar-with-tabs/src/2d60128e6bd2/src/de/arvidg/exampleactionbartabs/StartActivity.java).

If I modify the fragment class by

```
public class TestA extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);        
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Then my new layout comes over the action bar and tabs. But I want to show my new layout under the tabs.
Please help me.

Comment: Take a look here it can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853077/best-way-to-show-fragments-in-tabs/17853189#17853189

Comment: Thanks for reply. But not helping.

Comment: The code you give us doesn't help, post more code please. And be more precise in asking what you are trying to achieve !

Comment: Actually i want, like google play service we can select TopFree,TopPaid etc and show many item under tab and then we select our choiceable item and select. I want how to action under tab item action.

Comment: Use action Bar Sherlock, with a tabadapter

Comment: I can't using please if possible give a simple code. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Your layout comes on he actionbar because you are doing a startActivity, an activity will have the screen size by default, if you want to keep your tabs you must use fragments and fragmentTransitions

Comment: And do some research, internet is full of tuto. We can't do stuff in your place